# need level1,level2,level3,level4,level5,level6 result by recursive or connect by query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, hierarchical-data

My account structure is tree based:

| code | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 1-1 | kkk |
| 1-1-1 | dfgf |
| 1-1-1-1 | dfsd |
| 1-1-1-1-1-1 | sdfsd |
| 1-1-1-1-1-1-1 | sccdfsd |

I have 5000 records in this tree
need result level wise

grand-fmother  , father, child........

level1-tilte,level2-tilte,leve3-tilte,level4-tilte,level5-tilte,leve6-tilte,level7-tilte,level8-tilte,level9-tilte

How to get all parent title names level-wise in separate column?

Comment: need this type result title1 title2 title3 title4 title5 title6 title7 ....

Comment: can you explain the question little more!!

Answer (score 0):

You can detect number of elements in CODE column that defines levels of parenthood and use it in PIVOT to get the titles:

```sql
WITH      --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl AS
        ( Select '1' "CODE", 'abc' "TITLE" From Dual Union All
          Select '1-1' "CODE", 'kkk' "TITLE" From Dual Union All
          Select '1-1-1' "CODE", 'dfgf' "TITLE" From Dual Union All
          Select '1-1-1-1' "CODE", 'dfsd' "TITLE" From Dual Union All
          Select '1-1-1-1-1' "CODE", 'sdfsd' "TITLE" From Dual Union All
          Select '1-1-1-1-1-1' "CODE", 'sccdfsd' "TITLE" From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--  S Q L :
Select  Max(TITLE_1) "TITLE_1", Max(TITLE_2) "TITLE_2", Max(TITLE_3) "TITLE_3", 
        Max(TITLE_4) "TITLE_4", Max(TITLE_5) "TITLE_5", Max(TITLE_6) "TITLE_6"
From    ( Select    CODE, TITLE, Length(CODE) - Length(Replace(CODE, '-')) + 1 "LVL"
          From  tbl
        )
        PIVOT( Max(TITLE) For LVL IN(1 "TITLE_1", 2 "TITLE_2", 3 "TITLE_3", 
                                     4 "TITLE_4", 5 "TITLE_5", 6 "TITLE_6",
                                     7 "TITLE_7", 8 "TITLE_8", 9 "TITLE_9")  )
Order By CODE
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
TITLE_1 TITLE_2 TITLE_3 TITLE_4 TITLE_5 TITLE_6
------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
abc     kkk     dfgf    dfsd    sdfsd   sccdfsd   */
```

If you want to use connect by you can just change the inner sql like below:

```sql
Select  Max(TITLE_1) "TITLE_1", Max(TITLE_2) "TITLE_2", Max(TITLE_3) "TITLE_3", 
        Max(TITLE_4) "TITLE_4", Max(TITLE_5) "TITLE_5", Max(TITLE_6) "TITLE_6"
From    ( Select    CODE, TITLE, LEVEL "LVL"
          From  tbl
          Where LEVEL = Length(CODE) - Length(Replace(CODE, '-')) + 1
          Connect By LEVEL <= Length(CODE) - Length(Replace(CODE, '-')) + 1
        )
        PIVOT( Max(TITLE) For LVL IN(1 "TITLE_1", 2 "TITLE_2", 3 "TITLE_3", 
                                     4 "TITLE_4", 5 "TITLE_5", 6 "TITLE_6",
                                     7 "TITLE_7", 8 "TITLE_8", 9 "TITLE_9")  )
Order By CODE
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: If the data is a tree with multiple branches (or even multiple trees) then this will only output a single row and will combine data from different branches into the output when they are not related [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TQKPG5Vy). The OP has not stated what they expect in this case but it seems logically unexpected to get an output combining multiple branches (or trees); if you are always going to output a single row then it should probably be from a single branch from root to leaf.

Comment: @MT0 OP provided sample data with no expected result in question. In comment below the question there is the text "need this type result title1 title2 title3 title4 title5 title6 title7..." Yes, there could be so many things in OP's data but the sample data provided is all we have and those data are quite explicite and straightforward, aren't they? So, I just answered the question (and comment) without guessing anything. Your answer, in my opinion, is better, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of separators in the `code` hierarchy and determine the depth within the hierarchy from that and then use a hierarchical query to connect the rows and find all the titles using `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(title, ', '), 3) AS titles
FROM   (
  SELECT code,
         title,
         LENGTH(code) - LENGTH(REPLACE(code, '-')) AS depth
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH
       depth = 0
CONNECT BY
       code LIKE PRIOR code || '-%'
AND    depth = PRIOR depth + 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (code, title) AS
  SELECT '1',           'abc'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1-1',         'kkk'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1-1-1',       'dfgf'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1-1-1-1',     'dfsd'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1-1-1-1-1',   'sdfsd'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1-1-1-1-1-1', 'sccdfsd' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TITLES |
| --- |
| abc, kkk, dfgf, dfsd, sdfsd, sccdfsd |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HKPU_FNi)